# Use Regular Expression in Select mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a solution that uses regular expression in SELECT phrase in Mysql, as example  I have the following record

```
title = "title"
description = "this is testing title with id number 342 nice"
```

now I want to select the title and **342** from this record ( Note all description has `number` pattern) So I'm looking for a solution to select title and numbers in the description field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(<fieldname>,']',1),'[',-1) AS extracted
FROM <tablename>;
```

This should work

UPDATE:

```
SELECT title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description,']',1),'[',-1) AS extracted
FROM <tablename>;//Replace with your table name here
```

Comment: thank you for your attention can you provide the query?

Comment: Excellent, unfortunately after checking your solution I findout some records don't follow `[number]` pattern and just   `number` pattern, would you please update your solution?